# Handling large bitmaps on Android - int[] larger than max heap size

Tags: android, memory, android-ndk

I'm using very large bitmaps and I store data in a big int[]. The images can be really large and I can't downsample them (I'm getting the bitmaps over the wire and rendering them).

The problem I'm  hitting is on very large bitmaps (bitmap size = 64MB), where I try to allocate int array with size 16384000. I'm testing this on Samsung Galaxy SII, which should have enough memory to handle this, but it seems there is a "cap" on heap size. The method `Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()` returns 64MB, so this is the max heap size for this particular device.

The API level is set to 10, so I can't use `android:largeHeap` attribute suggested elsewhere (and I don't even know if that would help).

Is there any way to allocate more than 64MB? I tried allocating the array in native (using JNI `NewIntArray` function), but that fails as well. It seems as though it is bound by the same limit as jvm.

I could however allocate memory on the native side using `NewDirectByteBuffer`, but since this byte buffer is not backed by an array, I can not get access to `int[]` (using `asIntBuffer().array()` in java which I need in order to display the image using `setPixels` or `createBitmap`. I guess OpenGL would be a way to go, but I have (so far) 0 experience with OpenGL.

Is there a way to somehow access allocated memory as int[] that I am missing?

Comment: Is it really necessary to have 64MB bitmap on device? I mean, as long as it's bitmap you're receiving, it shouldn't be very difficult to downsample it during downloading.

Comment: The image is recieved as part of VNC protocol (it's a framebuffer). It is initialized and then the array is in-place updated with live data. I can't be downsampled while downloading. And I zoom on it as well. So it has to be as large as the sender is sending it (and with two monitors (this is a desktop image), you can quickly get to something like 5000x1920).

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm afraid you should be able to transfer framebuffer in pieces at least in order to get 5000x1920 Bitmap on device. Having one Bitmap of such size fits 64MB heap but having an int array of same size for updating framebuffer doesn't. Also OpenGl isn't any help for you. Textures consume memory in similar way as Bitmaps do.

Comment: harism, the transfer itself is not an issue. The rendering is. As for OpenGL, I believe it works with ByteBuffer, which can be allocated on the native side (without 64MB limit - tested).

Comment: Are you sure? Quick test `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(64 * 1024 * 1024)` crashed on my SGS2 at least. Also, don't forget to multiply byte buffer size with 4 once allocating one for int values.

Comment: Haris, I've mentioned in my question that I am able to allocate it on the native side (by using JNI `NewDirectByteBuffer` where you use malloc to allocate memory). And yes, the Java side of things (`allocateDirect`) fails miserably :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the only way I've found so far is to allocate image using NDK. Furthermore, since Bitmap does not use existing Buffer as pixel "storage" (the method `copyPixelsFromBuffer` is also bound to memory limits; and judging by the method name, it *copies* the data anyway).

The solution (I've only prototyped it roughly) is to `malloc` whatever the size of the image is, and fill it using c/c++ and then use ByteBuffer in Java with [OpenGLES](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html).

The current prototype creates a simple plane and applies this image as a texture to it (luckily, OpenGLES methods take Buffer as input, which seems to work as expected). I'm using `glTexImage2D` to apply this buffer as a texture to a plane. Here is a sample, where mImageData is ByteBuffer allocated (and filled) on the native side.

```
int[] textures = new int[1];
gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
mTextureId = textures[0];
gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureId);
gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_REPEAT);
gl.glTexImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL10.GL_RGBA, 4000, 4096, 0, GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, mImageData);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume OP already solved this, but if you have a Stream, you can stream the bitmap into a file and read that file using `inSampleSize`