# how to find out when Bitmap exceeds VM Budget?

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I saw a lot of questions about "Bitmap Exceeds VM Budget" Error and how to prevent and used tons of preventing solutions and codes in my app, But steel I'm getting that error in some of devices.

now I got tired and just want to know how can I find out when that problem occur (maybe with a "if" condition) so that I can tell user that  it's from his cell phone and in this way just prevent "Force Close" error.

this is my code:

```
public static Bitmap decodeFile(String filePath) {


    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o);

    final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 2048;

    int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
    int scale = 1;
    while (true) {
        if (width_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE && height_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE)
            break;

        width_tmp /= 2;
        height_tmp /= 2;
        scale *= 2;
    }

    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();


    o2.inSampleSize = scale;
    o2.inDither=false;                     
    o2.inPurgeable=true;                   
    o2.inInputShareable=true;              
    o2.inTempStorage=new byte[32 * 1024];

    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o2);

    return bmp;


}
```

any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Not much of a 'solution' but you can absolutely catch the OutOfMemoryError and handle accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The Google recomendation is not draw bigger images than 1024x1024 pixels, but I've found the solution below.

Google soluction: [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

Hard code soluction: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8067351/575643